# Are all the urls public, even in the administrator part?

Tags: security, url

is it possible for everyone, to see all the urls of a website? For example, in the administration part, a url like this : `www.___.com/administrator/admin.php?id=...`

Is it "public", and somehow everyone could see it? (i mean, not if you already know the url, i remember that it exists a white page with several folders from a website, i don't know how to NOT have this with my folders, or my urls : like if you know that there is administrator part in the website, you might not know that there is a url with "administrator/admin.php"... or maybe all the urls can be visible somewhere on the website, or with a software?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory no. But every URL you link from somewhere else, or otherwise publish to a third party (think referrers) can be indexed by search bots and other crawlers. On the top of that with a little trial and error a potential attacker (or just curious user) can find out about it, the `admin.php` or `/administration/` is not exactly uncommon on websites.

If you want to keep something secret, [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) never works out.

Comment: thanks, so the admin part is secured, with logins and passwords, and the only links are inside the admin part of the website. I'm wondering if i must secure the "admin" part of the website the same way as the "public" part

Answer (score 1):

URLs are URLs. A URL is something that a client sends to a server in an HTTP request. It is entirely up to the server how it responds to that request. It may show the content of the URL to anybody who asks. Or it may restrict it to clients with certain IP addresses. Or it may ask for a password for certain URLs.

As such, yes, all URLs are "public". But you can lock down the information behind these URLs in different ways if you want to.